# How can I completely delete the following programs using the Terminal?

Tags: performance

I am listing unneeded programs that are slowing down my computer by their exact names in Ubuntu Software. Can I please have a terminal command I can use to completely delete these programs?

- Archive Manager
- Backups
- Browser
- Calendar
- Character Map
- Checkbox
- Cheese
- Desktop Sharing
- Details
- IBus Preferences
- ImageMagick (display Q16)
- ImageMagick (display Q16)
- Input Method
- Language Support
- LibreOffice
- LibreOffice Calc
- LibreOffice Impress
- LibreOffice Math
- LibreOffice Writer
- Mahjongg
- Mines
- Onboard
- Online Accounts
- Passwords and Keys
- Personal File Sharing
- Power Statistics
- Remmina
- Rhythmbox
- Screen Reader
- Shotwell
- Simple Scan
- Software
- System Log
- Thunderbird Mail
- Transmission
- Vim
- xdiagnose
- XTerm

If any of these are absolutely vital, please tell me and I will remove them from the list.

Answer (score 7):

It's a common misconception that just having programs installed slows down computers. In fact, programs have absolutely no effect on performance at all unless you're using them or they run in the background. As it turns out, none of the programs you listed are good candidates to uninstall for performance reasons. However, if you insist on doing so anyway, you can use `apt-cache search` to find the package names, then `sudo apt-get remove` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to remove one of the ImageMagick programs, thinking it was doubled up by mistake. They work together as a team doing different things. If one is removed, things stop working properly. Install it back, computer runs fine again.